# React JS + Azure MVC: POST 404 (Not Found) when making API call

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, redux

I am making a POST API call from my React app to an Azure MVC controller. However, when I do, I receive the following error in the console:

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/SampleData/AcknowledgeRole 404 (Not
> Found)

This seems strange, considering that I have specified the `Route` in my Azure MVC controller. Below is my controller:

```
namespace Microsoft.IT.Security.OneAuthZUI.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
    using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
    using Microsoft.Enterprise.Authorization.Client.Legacy;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.IT.Security.OneAuthZUI.WebServices;
    using Microsoft.IT.Security.OneAuthZUI.WebServices.Helpers;
    using Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers;

    ////[Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
    public class SampleDataController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [Authorize]
        public void AcknowledgeRole(string acknowledgementInfo)
        {
            string[] components = acknowledgementInfo.Split("&");
            string assignmentId = components[0];
            string changeId = components[1];
            Console.WriteLine("assignmentId = " + assignmentId);
            Console.WriteLine("changeId = " + changeId);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the function in which I make the POST API call:

```
  public roleAcknowledge(roleAssignmentId: string, changeId: string) {
    return function() {
      // Send a POST request to the controller, passing in the roleAssignmentId and the changeId
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'api/SampleData/AcknowledgeRole', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

      // Use concatenation to send multiple parameters
      var parameters = roleAssignmentId + "&" + changeId;

      xhr.send(parameters);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The url shows localhost but you are mentioning on azure

Comment: @Sajeetharan Sorry, I am running the code locally, not on Azure :D

Comment: Your controller seems ok, you need to decorate your method parameter as `void AcknowledgeRole([FromQuery]string acknowledgementInfo)`. Do not use '&' in the query string as deliminator to concate 2 string instead use a different deliminate, because '&' is a special character split querstring and the string after '&' will be considered as next query string item.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the function like this,

```
   [HttpPost]
   [ActionName("AcknowledgeRole")]
   [Authorize]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the following error: http://localhost:3000/api/SampleData/AcknowledgeRole 404 (Not Found)

Comment: also you dont have to define the route again in controller

Comment: can you try to debug?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using `[HttpPost("[action]")]` and it actually worked which I wasn't aware of before because I normally use the `[Route]` attribute. I'm guessing the issue you're facing has something to do with your `cors` setting. Not sure how you configured `cors`, but since you're just running your application on localhost, try to configuring it to allow any and see if it would work. Just make sure not to deploy it to production.

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("AllowAnyPolicy", builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()));
```

Or, simply remove `[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]` for the meantime.